# emacs haskell-mode: <tab> does not work for if/then/else within do

Tags: if-statement, haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I'm programming Haskell (GHC 9.2.8) in Emacs 29.1 with `haskell-mode` 17.4 on Arch Linux, which works fine; including the REPL. However, I recently got frustrated a bit when working with effects, i.e. I'm trying to type in this dummy program:

```hs
getCmd :: IO String
getCmd  = do
  c <- getChar
  if c == 'n' then
    return "next"
  else
    return "previous"
```

However, as I'm typing, my cursor is stuck on the new line after the `else` keyword. When I press tab, nothing happens, and I have to indent the second return manually using spaces:

[image: Cursor stuck on new line after else keyword]

Am I using unidiomatic syntax, or is it an issue with my setup? How am I supposed to type this code?

Comment: although not an answer to your question, this is equivalent to `getCmd  = bool "previous" "next" . ('n' ==) <$> getChar`.

Comment: If you see the same thing when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (and you load Haskell mode), then consider filing a bug report with the maintainer of Haskell mode. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew When I run `emacs -Q Hello.cs` and type `M-x` `haskell-mode`, the mode cannot be loaded (`[No match]`).

Comment: *You* need to load the library using `load-library` or `require` or whatever... The point is to test with a virgin Emacs, with only support for Haskell mode loaded - nothing else from your init file.

Comment: In ancient times, `else` needed to be indented more than `if` to avoid an indentation error. (Maybe the mode is still assuming that? No idea.) Nowadays, the extra indentation is no longer required by GHC.

Comment: @chi When I put `then` on the next line, everything works; but `then` is indented by one additional level, same for `else`, as you described it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `then` on the same line caused the issue. This notation works:

[image]

So I can work with that and won't file a bug.